# Teamcity: how to run scheduled integration test only if the test build is green?

Tags: teamcity

I currently have the following situation: a project has

- a set of build configurations to run unit tests on the various commits we perform as we develop, and
- a subproject containing other build configurations to run integration tests.

The integration tests build configurations are tied to physical hardware, and it takes a few hours. Obviously we want to run these integration tests only twice a day, so they are on schedule trigger, rather than VCS. The problem is that we don't want to run the schedule trigger if the checkout that would be executed at the scheduled time is red at the unit test level.

Is there a way to communicate to the integration test build configurations that if they are going to run on something that is red (or currently not yet tested, there's this potential for a race condition) they should hold until a green build is available?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the snapshot dependency for this.

[image: snapshot dependency settings]

Unset **Only use successful builds from suitable ones** so that it wouldn't trigger a new build for the dependency if it's failed.

Then set **On failed dependency** option to "Cancel build".

Then you can use the scheduled trigger for this build configuration. Once the trigger fires, the build configuration will check the snapshot dependency rules and start or cancel depending on the conditions.